# Orange (Data mining tool) considering categorical value as String

Tags: data-mining, orange

I am new to using Orange tool for data mining. I have a csv file containing the data which is a mix of discrete and continuous values. However, it considers some of the discrete values as 'String'.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here or is it a problem with something else? In either case, I would like to know how to convert this 'String' value into discrete.

**Info about data:**
The file originally has 4 discrete values category contains 10-15 values(e.g. Tech, Media), topcat contains more than 100 values(Fashion, Art), location contains more than 200 values( e.g. New York, Boston), 
currency contains 5-10 values(USD, GBP).

The features topcat and location are considered as string by Orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can force Orange to interpret the variable as of type specified, e.g. to make a particular column a discrete variable, you have to set that column's header to contain `D#` (as per [the documentation](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/data/rst/index.html#header-with-attribute-type-information)).

Comment: Thanks @K3--rnc. I found this very useful and it solves the problem.